# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP_SSL' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am getting an error on my second line of code "server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='host_name', port=25)" that reads AttributeError: partially initialized module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP_SSL' (most likely due to a circular import)

I have the file saved as a .py file so that should not be the issue here.

Thank You,

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='host_name', port=25)

server.login("your username", "your password")

server.sendmail(
  "email@domain.com", 
  "email@domain.com", 
  "this message is from python")

server.quit()
```

Comment: My wager is that you saved this as `smtplib.py`.  That is, by definition, a circular import.  The `import smtplib` file will reload your file.

Comment: Encountered the same issue, my filename was `email.py` - changed it to something else, and it worked.